# If $f(x) = y$, is the limit of $f(x)$ as $n \to x$ = y?

Tags: calculus, limits

Some of you reading this may realize I just posted a question earlier.. but I just finished an assignment and I'm curious about something.

If I'm looking at a graph where there is a solid circle on $(2,2)$ and then an open circle on $(2,4)$, if $f(2) = 24$, and then a question below says $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)$, what does $f(2)$ mean ? Is it purely an evaluation? In my answers, I quoted the text and said it has no bearing as to whether the limit exists, but is merely an evaluation.

I suppose this may be a discussion question, I couldn't find an answer online.

Comment: Limit is about what value the function takes as you approach a particular $x$ value from NEARBY, not about what happens exactly AT a point. $f(x_0)$  and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ can be diferent values

Comment: So why is the book/my professor bothering to ask for the evaluation in a limits problem? Also, if the question is f(0) and there is no solid dot at x = 0, but the line does pass through (0,2), is f(0) = 2?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to x}{f(n)} = f(x) = y$ if $f$ is a continuous function. The example you described sounds like a discontinuity at $2$. This is what your lessons are trying to teach you about.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If $(0, 2)$ is a point on $f(x)$, then by definition $f(0) = 2$. Could you attach a pic showing f(x) graph and the point if possible ? :)

Comment: @ganeshie8 It depends on the definition. In the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, [english Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit) states $$0 < |x - c| < \delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$ Whereas [french Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limite_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29#Limite_d.27une_fonction_en_un_point) (and I'd say most french books) states $$|x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$ The english case is then called "limite épointée".

Comment: @ganeshie8 Thus, french definition of the limit is equivalent to continuity, when the function is defined at $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*$y=f(x)$ is just a notational representation. f is a function which acts on $x$ which is in the domain of f and maps it to a unique value in the range of f. We call this value of f at x by a point y in the range. $f(x)$ is just a value which the function f takes at the point $x$.*

*It has nothing to do with limit of f. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ means how the function f behaves at the point x which is nearing a. Did you get this difference ?*

Comment: So if f(x) and f(x) as n->x are the same, is that the limit?

Comment: @pbrianq But what do you mean by "$f(x)$ as $n\rightarrow x$" ??? There is no $n$ in $f(x)$!

Comment: I mean if the limit of f(x) as n->x is in the same spot as the value of f(x), assuming its not discontinuous

Comment: @pbrianq, there is no n, please see what you are asking. You can say $x\to x_0$. Please read the answer I have posted carefully.

Comment: I created n.. I was just asking hypothetically